# MVC5 Hang on SignInManager.PasswordSignIn (and Async)

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

The below only hangs on the server, not in any of our local devs.  We are successfully connecting to the test database in the Stage environment where my app is failing.

I am making an Ajax call to the login method of Account controller.

In an effort to troubleshoot the server, I have stripped this controller down to the login method and returning a very simple view.

The Call (Ajax):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "login-Form", @class = "myForm form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    { 
         <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
<script>    

    $(function () {        
        $('#login-Form').ajaxForm({
            success: function (result) {
                $('#downloadSection').html(result);
                $('#dynamicMessage').empty().html('<h1 style="float: left;">You may now download any of the files on the right.</h1>')
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $('#downloadSection').html("There was an error of type(" + status + "): " + error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My stripped down controller action looks like this:

```
        // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {                
        var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

       return PartialView("MyPartialView", "It will never get this far anyway.");
    }
```

I have verified that the correct info is being sent in the model. That means I am getting email and password (not something like user name).

This does not work on either my stage or production server running iis 7.5

I just get a page hang... why isn't this exiting the SignInManager.PasswordSignIn method and continue to return with partial view?

Edit / Update:
I cleared the database and ran the update-database for migrations in the pmc. It worked for a second. The moment I changed a role in a security attribute decorating one of my controllers and then published... back to hang. WTH?

Answer (score -1):

so your passwordsignin method carries 4 parameters 1 for either your username or as you used email, second for your password, third is a bool that handles is persitent and fourth is also a bool for shouldlockout.

Do not mind my many explanation just try this and i hope it works for you.

var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, false,false);

Comment: To hope that it is working is never a good idea. You have to know why it is working!